# linux sed replace string with env variable

Tags: linux

I have an environment variable

HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy:3128

In one of my config.yaml file, I have a line :-

ProxyAddress: ""

I am trying to replace this with :-

ProxyAddress: "http://proxy:3128"

through command :-

```
sed -i "s|ProxyAddress: ""|ProxyAddress: \"${HTTP_PROXY}|g;" cfg.yaml
```

Result of this is :-

ProxyAddress: "http://proxy:3128"" , it as adding an extra quote at the end.

Comment: Escaping issue ? `sed -i "s|ProxyAddress: \"\"|ProxyAddress: \"${HTTP_PROXY}\"|g;" cfg.yaml`

Comment: When i try this sed -i "s|ProxyAddress: \"\"|ProxyAddress: \"${HTTP_PROXY}\"|g;" cfg.yaml. It set ""http:/proxy:3128"". Dont think its an escaping issue

Answer (score 0):

Correct expression would be

```
sed -i 's|ProxyAddress: ""|ProxyAddress: \"'${HTTP_PROXY}'\"|g;" cfg.yaml
```